# Problem importing AgGridModule with community version

Tags: ag-grid-angular

Followed instructions in https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-angular, got error on the step:
Adding `AgGridModule.withComponents([])` in `app.module.ts`:

> ERROR in node_modules/ag-grid-angular/lib/ag-grid-angular.module.d.ts:3:46 - error NG6005: AgGridModule.withComponents returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument. Please add a generic type argument to the ModuleWithProviders type. If this occurrence is in library code you don't control, please contact the library authors.

```
static withComponents(components?: any): ModuleWithProviders;
```

And then if I add the import without components:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AgGridModule
  ],
```

Then I got following error:

> ERROR in node_modules/ag-grid-angular/lib/ag-grid-angular.module.d.ts:2:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
> This likely means that the library (ag-grid-angular) which declares AgGridModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I am also facing same issue did you find any solution on this?